# Is there any relation between a private IP and a public IP is any win/linux systems, if yes -> how are they related?

Tags: networking

For example a win machine has one nic card with a private IP assigned to it, if it also has a public IP -> where that pulic IP is connected to(On the same NIC card or is it coming from a router )

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no automatic relationship between the two at all. The translation is usually done by a router (gateway), invisibly to the host.

- When you're in a situation where your machines have private IPs and must "share" a single public IP, then the translation between the two (NAT) is usually done by a *router*, and the hosts don't even know that this is happening. The public IP address is usually assigned to the same router.
- When you're using one of those cloud-hosting providers where machines have private IPs but can be assigned a "floating" public IP, this is commonly done using 1:1 NAT in the same way as above. (Hosting providers usually do this to avoid needing manual reconfiguration.)
- There are of course networks which directly assign a public IP address to hosts – this is common on datacenters, for example. But in those situations – when your machine is *directly* assigned a public IP address – then you would literally see it in the NIC's "status", it would show up in `ipconfig`, and so on.

If an address shows up in `ipconfig` or `ip addr`, then it's assigned to your machine. If it *doesn't* show up in ipconfig, then it's assigned to a router (NAT gateway).

Comment: Port-forwarding relates here, so external address x.x.x.x:y will go, on a normal domestic connection, to your router at x.x.x.x and your router can be set to forward traffic on the y port to a particular client in the local network.

Comment: Port forwarding is still just NAT.

Comment: @pbhj Another term for "port forwarding" is "destination NAT", where the public IP address found in the header field of the IP packet is replaced with the private address. In that, it's basically the opposite of what people usually refer to as "NAT" which is effectively "source NAT".

Comment: I wasn't disagreeing, I just thought that might have been what the questioner was trying to get to, ie a way to associate an external IP with a specific internal host. Which I guess is still network address translation (NAT) but might not have been an obvious result to the OP.